# How do I get an array to work with a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to get the code to output the code below. I'm a little knew at this, so I don't understand how to fix it, and I tried googling it up but I couldn't find any solution.

```
var arrayName = [
  $('nav ul li:first-child a'),
  $('nav ul li:last-child a')
]

newsNav[1].on('click', {
  alert('works');
});
```

Desired Output:

```
$('nav ul li:first-child a').on('click', {
  alert('works');
});
```

Comment: `newsNav` is not defined... Perhaps you mean `arrayName[1].click..`? (Or, more likely, `arrayName` should be `newsNav`.

Comment: Also, arrays start at index 0, so it should be `newsNav[0]` if you do want `first-child` and not `last-child`.

Comment: And `{alert('works');}` is not exactly valid JavaScript syntax if I remember right. Not without a `function()` before it, I mean.

Comment: working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uxtu6qm3/10/

Comment: @Rasel Even with changing all that, it doesn't seem to show an alert for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments above are your answer.
So your code should be looks like this...

```
var arrayName = [$('nav ul li:first-child a'),
  $('nav ul li:last-child a')];

arrayName[1].on('click', function(){
  alert('works');
});
```